# windows 10 Pro + windows update + recovery key

Tags: windows, windows-10, bitlocker

I rent a server (a high performance one) just to store backups of my data. There's software running in the background scanning my drive and sending files to the external server which in turn copies the same data to multiple drives.

I had some critical data which (long story short) did not make it to the server.

I specifically set windows update to postpone any non tested updates by the community (not sure how the option is called but it is available on ms windows 10 as 'postponed updates').

Today after an update bitlocker asked my for a recovery key. There has been nothing changed to the hardware nor did I flash any firmware.

I don't have the recovery key. I had a copy on a pendrive which was taken from me at the airport in Bangkok

What can I do?

Comment: What exactly is a `rexovery key`?

Comment: you want me to tell you my bitlocker recovery key?

Comment: When the vulgar language is removed the grammatical mistakes are fixed I will reverse my downvote.

Comment: I absolutely do not want your recover key.  I asked what you mean by `rexovery key`.  Any event if you don't have the recovery key then you are out of luck. Due to the nature of how Bitlocker works, if it's asking for the recovery key, the only thing that can be done is provide the recovery key.  If you cannot provide the recovery key then you are simply out of luck, access to your encrypted drive will simply not be possible.

Comment: my laptop is dead i had half a million  worth of  private keys on this peace of junk yes I feel sort of emotional. writing from an ipad so typos are present. admins can remove this post I dunnot care. I mean why would microsoft flash anything to my hardware without notice

Comment: They actually didn't.  It sounds like you postponed cumulative updates for 15 days but after that period of time, you were also told through notifications, that updates were ready to be installed.  If you didn't at that time select your active hours and/or schedule the update for a better time that is entirely on you.

Comment: Still, why would a cumulative update trigger bitlocker recovery. From what I know Bitlocker does rely on checksums of hardware components in the system.

Comment: in my setup there is a TPM module which stores private key which in turn is encrypted to the PIN number which I input at every startup. From what I know I shouldnt have expected invalidation of previous checksums used by bitlocker wfter any kind of windows update.

Comment: There are numerous reasons it could have happened.  A recovery key will be requested whenever Bitlocker believes the volume that is being loaded isn't the same machine that was used to encrypt it when a TPM is used.  If you have a Microsoft Surface product, and the update included firmware, that could have been one reason that happened.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64016/discussion-between-ramhound-and-rafal).

Comment: it is not a Microsoft machine it is Asus Zenbook Pro and in my honest opinion. This just shouldn't have happened If the entire update process was designed properly.